# Android studio xml file not readable and xml files became textfiles

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, text-files

[image: Error reading the xml files they are like textfiles, how to fix this. Thanks in advance]

Error reading the xml files they are like textfiles, how to fix this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. 
**File -> Invalidate Cashes and Restart** pressed 
and that fixed everything))